# how to add AVPlayer to UIView in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I my `UIViewController` I have an outlet to `UIView`, where I would like to display video using external links. In this case I try to create `AVPlayerLayer` and add it to my `UIView` outlet.

My code looks like that:

```
class VievController: UICollectionViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yE_XgoWBso"))!)
            let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
            playerLayer.frame = playerView.bounds
            playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            playerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            avPlayer.play()
    }
}//end class
```

I don't know why I don't see video on my `UIVIew` outlet - nothing happened. Do you have any suggestion what should I fix?

Comment: just implement AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate and your good to go

Answer (score 3):

```
Below code help you to solve the issue

Adjust the frame according to your needs

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
  NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPP6lXaL7KA&feature=youtube_gdata_player"];
  AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:urlString]];
  avPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
  self.songPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
  self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer: self.songPlayer];
  self.avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
  UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
  [newView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
  [self.view addSubview:newView];
  [ self.songPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Your answer *may* be correct, but the question specifically asks for **Swift** code examples, not Objective-C. Please edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot use AVPlayer to play YouTube, Vimeo, etc.
For that purpose you'll have to use UIWebView.

Answer (score 2):

```
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("ding.mp3", withExtension: nil)
    guard let newURL = url else {
         print("Could not find file:")
        return
    }
    do {

        backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        //print(error.description)
    }
```

You jus need to import avfoundation framework then use this above code

Comment: i asked about loading video from external link not from bundle

Answer (score 0):

```
    // avPlayer
    let url = URL(string:myURL) let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    
    // avpController
    let avpController = AVPlayerViewController() avpController.player = player
    
    // addSubView then set size or constraint
    self.videoView.addSubview(avpController.view)
    
    avpController.view.frame.size.height = videoView.frame.size.height
    avpController.view.frame.size.width = videoView.frame.size.width
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, so figured out the reason that playing video from YouTube url is having issue. So app transport security might have issue with it.
If you try to play a video from app's document directory this code will surely work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).